# How to return string instead of boolean in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this problem

Given an string and a dictionary of words, find out if the input string can be broken into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

```
dictionary = ["I" , "have", "Jain", "Sumit", "am", "this", "dog"]

String = "IamSumit"

Output: "I am Sumit"

String ="thisisadog"

Output : String can't be broken
```

My function is giving me `boolean` output instead of string `result` I tried like this `return result;`. still returning boolean

```
const find = (S,dic ,result) =>{
        if (S.length === 0) {
            console.log(result,'kkkk')
            return result;
        }else {
            let index = 0,
                word = "";

            while (index < S.length){
                word += S.charAt(index);
                if (dic.indexOf(word) !==-1) {
                    if (find(S.substring(index + 1), dic, result + word + " ")) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        //System.out.println(word + "  backtrack");
                        index++;
                    }
                }else{
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    console.log(find("thisisadog",["I" , "have", "Jain", "Sumit", "am", "this", "dog"],''))
```

Comment: you return true and return false ... these are booleans, if you want to return a string, then return a string - the only time your function returns `result` is if you pass in the first argument with length 0

Comment: I tried to pass `result`.!! but not succeed could you please change my function

Comment: yes, you did, and the only time you return it is if `S.length == 0` ... which it doesn't ... as I don't know what your code is even doing, I can't "change your function"

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you need to do, but I didn't well understand how your code works, so I implemented my version of it.

```
const splitStringFromDict = (str, dict) => {
    let index = 0, word = "", result = [];
    while (index < str.length) {
        word += str.charAt(index);
        if (dict.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
            result.push(word);
            word = ""
        }
        index++;
    }
    if (word !== "") result.push(word);

    for (word of result) {
        if (dict.indexOf(word) === -1){
            return "String can not be broken";
        }
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}
```

It's not an recursive function, and I think it's slightly easier to follow.

Now, I should probably emphasise that naming a function by the same name of an existing function in `Array.prototype`, is not a good practice at all. 
More about clean code tips [here](https://github.com/ahmedhammad97/Clean-Code-Do-And-Dont).

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors like you use (return true/false) instead of string value return. Except in

```
 if (S.length === 0) {
  console.log(result,'kkkk')
  return result;
        }
```

Due to which it returns the boolean value and i have fixed the code according to your desire output.

```
const find = (S,dic ,result,broken) =>{
    if (S.length === 0) {
        console.log(result)
        return result;
    }

    else {
        let index = 0,
            word = "";

        while (index < S.length){
            word += S.charAt(index);
            if (dic.indexOf(word) !==-1) {
                if (find(S.substring(index + 1), dic, result + word + " ")) {
                    return result;

                } else {
                    //System.out.println(word + "  backtrack");
                    index++;
                }
            }else{
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    return broken;
}

console.log(find("IamSumit",["I" , "have", "Jain", "Sumit", "am", "this", "dog"],'',`String can't be broken`))
```

Output:

```
String = "IamSumit"

Output: "I am Sumit"

String ="thisisadog"

Output : 'String can`t be broken'
```